# Differential equation involving two unknown functions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

I'm solving a problem about surfaces and I got to this differential equation: $$f'g'' - f''g' + \frac{g'}{f} = 0,$$

where $f, g : I \subset \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ are functions of one variable, $f > 0,$ and they satisfy $$(f')^2 + (g')^2 = 1  \implies g'g'' + f'f'' = 0. $$

I'm not sure how to solve it in order to determine $f$ and $g$.

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We start with
\begin{align*}
f'g''-f''g'+\frac{g'}{f}&=0 \\
f'g'g''-f''g'^2+\frac{g'^2}{f}&=0 \quad \text{(multiply by $g'$)} \\
-f'(f'f'')-f''(1-f'^2)+\frac{1-f'^2}{f}&=0 \quad \text{(substitute from other equation)} \\
-f'^2f''-f''+f'^2f''+\frac{1}{f}-\frac{f'^2}{f}&=0 \\
-f''+\frac{1}{f}-\frac{f'^2}{f}&=0 \\
ff''+f'^2&=1 \\
\frac{d}{dx}(ff')&=\frac{d}{dx}(x) \\
ff'&=x+C_1 \\
\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{f^2}{2}\right)&=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{x^2}{2}+C_1x\right) \\
\frac{f^2}{2}&=\frac{x^2}{2}+C_1x+C_2 \\
f&=\pm\sqrt{x^2+C_1x+C_2},
\end{align*}
where we have absorbed the $2$ into $C_1$ and $C_2$. But now, since $f>0,$ we can throw out the negative solution, obtaining
$$f(x)=\sqrt{x^2+C_1x+C_2}.$$
Now to find $g,$ we start with a previous step and substitute as follows:
\begin{align*}
f&=(x^2+C_1x+C_2)^{1/2} \\
f'&=\frac{x+C_1/2}{(x^2+C_1x+C_2)^{1/2}} \\
f'^2&=\frac{(x+C_1/2)^2}{x^2+C_1x+C_2} \\
1-g'^2&=\frac{x^2+C_1x+C_1^2/4}{x^2+C_1x+C_2} \\
g'^2&=1-\frac{x^2+C_1x+C_1^2/4}{x^2+C_1x+C_2}\\
&=\frac{x^2+C_1x+C_2-x^2-C_1x-C_1^2/4}{x^2+C_1x+C_2}\\
&=\frac{C_2-C_1^2/4}{x^2+C_1x+C_2}.
\end{align*}
Solving this separable equation is routine, but tedious. Mathematica yields
$$g(x)= \pm\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{4 C_2-C_1{}^2} \ln \left(2
    \sqrt{C_1 x+C_2+x^2}+C_1+2 x\right).$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! :) I worked it out from the previous answer, but got confused with solving for $g$.

Answer (score 0):

Solve for $g'[r]$:

$$
g'[r] = \pm\sqrt{1-f'[r]^2}
$$

and find

$$
0=-1 + f'^2 + f f''
$$
whose solution is

$$
f^2 = r^2 + 2 c_1 r + c_1^2 - e^{2c_3} 
$$

Comment: Could you maybe flesh out these steps a bit more? It's not easy to follow.

Comment: From the ODE $$ff''+f'^{2}-1=0$$ you get $$(ff')'-1=0 \implies ff' = x + c_{1} \implies \frac{f^{2}}{2} = \frac{x^{2}}{2} + c_{1}x + c_{2} \implies f^{2} = x^{2}+2c_{1}x+\color{red}{2c_{2}}$$ I'm not sure how you got $\color{blue}{c_{1}^{2} - e^{2c_{3}}}$, or how you got _three_ integration constants from a _second_ order DE.

Comment: Hi, you are right that it is nicer to write the constants as you do. There are only two constants in my answer but it is perhaps a little confusing.